# Python: Converting JsonL to Json to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, type-conversion, jsonlines

currently working with jsonl files and I intend to convert it into CSV format to run it through a program. However, I realize that it would be better to convert it from json directly to CSV instead, and I wrote a code below to convert json to csv. However, I am unsure on how I can convert my current jsonl files into the desired json format before I can run this code. If anyone has any solutions for me, do let me know! Thanks so much for the read and appreciate all the help that I can get.

(FYI I tried to convert the jsonl file directly using the json to csv converter below and I get an  error message below:)

```
Converting to CSV: XXX.jsonl
ERROR: Extra data
```

This is the conversion code, I hope it helps!

```
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
import pandas as pd
import sys
from flatten_json import flatten
import json

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) not in [1, 2]:
        sys.exit("Usage: python JsonCon.py [FILENAME.json] \n exitted")

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    print(f"Converting to CSV: {filename}")
    convertFile(filename)

def convertFile(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            jsString = json.load(file)
            dic_flat = [flatten(d) for d in jsString]
            df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flat)
            df.to_csv(f'{filename[:-5]}.csv')
    except JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f'ERROR: {e.msg}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: jsonl is basically a sequence of json, one for every lines. So just cicle over each line of jsonl and apply your script. Then concatenates the results. to_csv with None parameter will return a string.

Comment: Hi @Yuri, any idea on how to do that? I'm just starting off with python and I'm really hoping I could get a little guidance along the way. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import json
import csv
import io

# get the JSON objects from JSONL
jsonl_data = """{"a": 1, "b": 123}\n{"a": 2, "b": 234}\n{"a": 3, "b": 345}\n"""
json_lines = tuple(json_line
                   for json_line in jsonl_data.splitlines()
                   if json_line.strip())
jsons_objs = tuple(json.loads(json_line)
                   for json_line in json_lines)

# write them into a CSV file
fake_file = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(fake_file)
writer.writerow(["a", "b"])
writer.writerows((value for key, value in sorted(json_obj.items()))
                 for json_obj in jsons_objs)
print(fake_file.getvalue())
```

Comment: jsons_as_list is missing

Comment: @Yuri Indeed, I fixed my answer.